# How to Integrate facebook login in phonegap application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-login

I am creating an android application using phonegap, have tried installing plugin like InAppBrowser etc, but nothing is working for me, I have created AppID and App Name in Facebook developer account,

Here is the link i have followed

> https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/

Please share an idea to implement the facebook login integration in Phonegap application.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this [OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) for integrating facebook login, just to follow simple steps add `openfb.js` to your code and the one plugin inAppBrowser is needed to open this fb login screen.

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully use this [plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). Let's have a look on it

EDIT: Someone ask more details. Here you are:

```
// Verify if already logged: if not, login:
            var already_logged_success = function (data)
            {
                if (data && data.authResponse && data.authResponse.userID && data.authResponse.accessToken) 
                {
                    var userID = data.authResponse.userID;
                    var token = data.authResponse.accessToken;
                    send_token(token,userID,email);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Connection issue: login again
                    call_login_fb();
                }
            }        
            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(already_logged_success, function (error) {
                    // User not logged: login now
                    call_login_fb();
            });

            var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {                    
                    // userData: {"authResponse":{"userID":"1017897733282449","accessToken":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","session_key":true,"expiresIn":"5183999","sig":"..."},"status":"connected"}
                    var userID = userData.authResponse.userID;
                    var token = userData.authResponse.accessToken;
                    if (userID && token) 
                    {
                        send_token(token,userID,email);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var err_string = "Facebook error";
                        console.log(err_string);
                        alert(err_string);
                    }
            }

            function call_login_fb()
            {
                facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                    fbLoginSuccess,
                    function (error) {
                        var err_string = "Facebook error";
                        console.log(err_string);
                        alert(err_string);
                    }
                );
            }
```

The send_token function send the token to my server and give access to the user.

Comment: Hello @Zappescu, can you please tell me if this plugin returns friends list too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think so. Since it can allows access to the Facebook Graph API (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#the-graph-api) and following the official graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/), I think it'll be possibile.

Comment: This means I can access any of my friends friend list with his/her `{user-id}/friendlists`, actually, I am creating an app for sharing location with friends and I need a friends list of facebook to share location with them all or selected friends. Thanks btw.

Comment: Hello @Zappescu, I have uses the same plugin you suggest, I have followed the steps in the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/), now the FB Login is pop up in my app while click the FB Login button, but after login it does not navigate to any new page. may I know whether I have done anything wrong in the precedure. please share any reference for FB Login for Phonegap application.